# laravel - get view with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel

I am wondering why I can't have 2 parameters on a get route, with laravel 5.7

Why doesn't this work

```
Route::get('/test/{test1}/{test2}', 'Auth\RegisterController@test');

public function test($test1, $test2){  
    return view('test', ['test1' => $test1] );
}
```

when this works?

```
Route::get('/test/{test1}', 'Auth\RegisterController@test');

public function test($test1){  
    return view('test', ['test1' => $test1] );
}
```

here is test.blade.php

```
<registration test1="{{ $test1 }}" test2="{{ $test2 }}"></registration>
```

when I add test2, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" exception. if I remove it everywhere, no exception...

and in vuejs view

```
  props:{
      test1: null,
      test2: null
  },
```

and here is what I call

```
http://127.0.0.1/test/5c61c2eb6f334/fyujk
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are not passing your all variables to view.

It should be like this:

```
Route::get('/test/{test1}/{test2}', 'Auth\RegisterController@test');

public function test($test1, $test2){  
    return view('test', ['test1' => $test1, 'test2' => $test2] );
}
```

Or a more good way:

```
public function test($test1, $test2){  
    return view('test', compact('test1','test2'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I keep getting this error : Unexpected token < no matter which view I use. It works well with one parameter... I really don't understand this strange issue!

Comment: Do you have this '<' in your second parameter?
it is attempting to interpret the angle bracket as an html tag.

Comment: no, this is the very weird thing... here is the route http://127.0.0.1/test/5c61c2eb6f334/fyujk

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple parameters in many ways, here is one:

`public function test($test1, $test2){ 
  return view('test')->with(compact('test1','test2'));
}`

Comment: Thanks! I keep getting this error : 'Unexpected token <' when adding a second character, no matter if I use compact or ['test1' => $test1, 'test2' => $test2].

Comment: arre you sure you dont have a < in your second parameter?

Comment: absolutely sure. i tried with everything. I updated the question with the rest of the code (i have tried this with different routes, always failed...)

Answer (score 0):

How i always pass my variables is like this:

```
public function test($test1, $test2){ 
    return view('store.stores', compact('test1', 'test2'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, no success either :'( (I updated my question)

Answer (score 0):

or better still, you can do it this way:

```
Route::get('/test/{test1}/{test2}', 'Auth\RegisterController@test');

public function test($test1, $test2){ 

    $data['test1']=$test1;
    $data['test2']=$test2;

    return view('test',$data);

}
```

//on your view, you can then do this:

```
{{ $test1 }}

{{ $test2 }}
```

Comment: thanks julius, I tried your solution without any success. I updated my question with the rest of the code..